# Something about a particle in a delta-function potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, s-matrix-theory

This is the part about the delta-function potential in the Introduction To Quantum Mechanics by Griffiths.[image]

It is the scattering state, where E>0.[image]
I wonder why G must be 0 if the particles are fired from the left? Does it mean the moving direction of the wave represent the moving direction of the particle? But in my mind, in quantum mechanics, motion is a classical sense. Position is made sure by the measurement.
I guess I have not understood the relationship of the moving wave and the particle thoroughly. I will be very grateful if someone explains it to me.
If I have not made my question clear, I hope you can point it out, since English is my second language.

Comment: In the analysis a "particle" is represented by a plane wave. (More or less the whole foundation of QM.)  So the propagation vector $\mathbf{k}$ (which is equal to $\pm k\hat{x}$ in this case) indicates the direction of motion. When you set up the problem you decide where the incoming wave (or particle) must come from and then set the coefficient of the other one to zero.

Comment: @flippiefanus So you mean that the particle is moving towards right if the wave is propagating in the right direction?

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score -1):

What is explained by Griffiths is the fact that, when you have E > 0, is the situation of free particle, right after the potential barrier.So we have a condition of non-normalization, because the wave function is $Ae^{ikx}$. 
Only when you have the $\psi(x,0)$ you can determine the all package of wave. Remember for the free particle solution, you don't have a function wave, but a package of wave, which is normalizable. Is the same here.

If you have E<0, then you have binding states, so the wave function is normalizable.